# How to exclude routing module from karma coverage?

Tags: angular, jasmine

My karma coverage is trying to cover my routing modules, and, i don't think there's important tests to do with that, so i'm trying to exclude this modules from karma coverage.

I tried to put in angular.json:

```
"test": {
   "options": {
       "codeCoverageExclude": ["*.module.routing.ts"]
   }
}
```

But my routing modules is still trying to be coverage.
Example: `sidenav.module.routing.ts`:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'configs',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../../configs/configs.module').then(
        (module) => module.ConfigsModule
      ),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class SidenavRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this putting the correct path:

```
"codeCoverageExclude": ["/**/*module.routing.ts"]
```

Now my karma is not trying to coverage routing modules.